# Wrong sum with aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to run this query:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "_exists_:products_count",
            "default_operator": "AND"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "pid": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "pid",
        "size": 15,
        "order": {
          "products_counter": "ASC"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "products_counter": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "products_count"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The results I get are:

```
{
  "took": 5,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 12,
    "successful": 12,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 489681,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "pid": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": -1,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 488443,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 3229479298,
          "doc_count": 14,
          "products_counter": {
            "value": 26
          }
        },
        {...
```

Although the results for the pid returned are 188 and not 26.
if I raise the size of the aggregation from 15 to 100000 for example I do get the right number.
any help with understanding and fixing my problem?

Comment: This should explain the issue you're seeing: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-approximate-counts

Comment: @Val Hi, I'm using just one shard :/

Comment: I see 12 shards in your ES response.

Comment: @Val Opps :O
So there is no way of making the results accurate?

Comment: Yes, by increasing the size as you did.

Comment: @Val No other way but reducing the shards or razing the size?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, there's no magic behind that.

Comment: Note that if you don't have too many documents, one shard is more than enough.